# What is the importance of default Get() constructor in hbase

Tags: hbase

What is the importance of default Get() constructor in hbase? Is it to return all the rows in the table? I'm trying to use it but it takes forever.

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();   
HTable table0 = new HTable(conf, "test");
Get get0 = new Get();
Result result0 = table0.get(get0);
byte[] val0 = result0.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("e1"));

System.out.println("Value: " + Bytes.toString(val0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not important, you shouldn't be using it. If you read the documentation you will see that you shouldn't be using. it says.

```
Constructor for Writable. DO NOT USE
```

I believe that you using an old client because this constructor doesn't exist anymore. You should always specify the row you want to get in the constructor or provide another get to copy.

What do you want to achieve? A full table scan? Then this how you do it.

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
ResultScanner results = table.getScaner(scan);
...
```